# PDO general error when using fetch after insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, error-handling

I'm trying to fetch data from the db using `fetchAll()`, which works unless I try to do so right after an `insert` query. The error I keep getting is a "General error". I read online that this is a know issue:

> It seems that if you do a `$statement->query()` with an INSERT statement and after that a `$statement->fetch()` you will get an exception saying: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error. [source](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Is there any way to go around this?

### My code

First I'm running an insert query:

```
INSERT INTO question (`qid`, `question`, `category`, `subcategory`, `explanation`, `answer_type`, `answer_options`, `answer_nav`, `answer_optional`) VALUES ('65', 'TEST', 'wisselvraag', 'wk 1 - wk 1', '<strong>Let op! Maak aantekening bij vraag.</strong>', 'yes_no', '{null,null}', '', '1')

private function get($columns = "*", $dump = false)
{
    $this->select($columns);
    $this->prepareSQL();
    if ($dump === true) {
        $this->dumpSQL();
        return [];
    }

    $this->stmt = $this->getPdo()->prepare($this->query);
    $this->stmt->execute();


    $this->incrementAmountOfQueries();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Right after doing that I run a `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT question.* FROM question JOIN questionlist_question ON questionlist_question.`question_id` = question.`id` WHERE question.`category` = 'wisselvraag' AND questionlist_question.`questionlist_id` = '7' ORDER BY question.`qid` DESC LIMIT 1
```

To

```
$this->stmt->execute();
$this->stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My data. The `fetchAll()` seems to be the problem.

```
/**
 * prepare an INSERT query
 * @param array $data
 * @return bool
 */
private function insert(Array $data)
{
    $fields = "";
    $values = "";

    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        $value = htmlentities($value);
        $fields .= "`$field`, ";
        $values .= "'$value', ";
    }

    $fields = trim($fields, ", ");
    $values = trim($values, ", ");
    $this->insert = "($fields) VALUES ($values)";

    $this->incrementAmountOfQueries();

    return $this->execute();
}

 /**
 * Execute a query
 * @return bool
 */
private function execute()
{
    $this->prepareSQL();
//    print($this->query);
//    exit;
    $this->stmt = $this->getPdo()->prepare($this->query);
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}
```

**$This->stmt**

`$this->stmt` is defined as `$this->stmt = $this->getPdo()->prepare($this->query);`

**getPdo()**

```
/**
 * Get PDO instance
 * @return \PDO
 */
private function getPdo()
{
    if (!$this->pdo) {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new \PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (\Exception $err) {
            print_r($err);
            exit;
        }
    }

    return $this->pdo;
}
```

**$this->query**

```
private function prepareSQL()
{
    $sql = "";
    if ($this->insert) {
        if ($this->table) {
            $sql .= "INSERT INTO " . $this->table;
            $sql .= " " . $this->insert;
        }
    } else {
        if ($this->select) $sql .= "SELECT " . $this->select;
        if ($this->table) $sql .= " FROM " . $this->table;
        if ($this->join) $sql .= " " . $this->join;
        if ($this->where) $sql .= " " . $this->where;
        if ($this->order) $sql .= " " . $this->order;
        if ($this->limit) $sql .= " LIMIT " . $this->limit;
    }
    $this->query = $sql;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Because an INSERT doesn't return anything performing a fetch is a pointless exercise. You could do a SELECT after the INSERT and fetch the results of the SELECT.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I'll edit the question to clarify this

Comment: Please show the definition of `$stmt`.

Comment: Added it :) @eggyal

Comment: So as I said - your wrapper is prone to every issue possible, from SQL injection to weird overlapping results. Do yourself a favor, make it *simpler*

Comment: @YourCommonSense, your username checks out.

Comment: It's quite simple, I just forgot 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I suppose you are returning this value from a function. Well, return a statement instead. And then chain a fetchAll() to your function call later, if you need to get the rows. **You won't believe how enormously flexible your function will become.**

You can check an example section for this kind of function: [all this stuff](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#samples) is available only thanks to a statement returned.

You may also would like to read my other article, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes) as I am sure your wrapper has other issues.