# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, resultset

this error happened while i was trying to create an insert query

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in E:\xammp\htdocs\school\private\core\database.php:29 Stack trace: #0 E:\xammp\htdocs\school\private\core\database.php(29): PDOStatement->fetchAll(5) #1 E:\xammp\htdocs\school\private\core\model.php(40): Database->query('insert into use...', Array) #2 E:\xammp\htdocs\school\private\controllers\Home.php(18): Model->insert(Array) #3 E:\xammp\htdocs\school\private\core\app.php(33): Home->index() #4 E:\xammp\htdocs\school\public\index.php(6): App->__construct() #5 {main} thrown in E:\xammp\htdocs\school\private\core\database.php on line 29

this is the query

```
public function query($query, $data = array(),$data_type = "object"){
  

        $con = $this -> connect();
        $stm = $con->prepare($query);  

        if($stm){
            $check = $stm -> execute($data);//check if the statment excuted or it went well
            if($check){
               if ($data_type == "object") {
                    $data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
               }else{
                    $data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
               }
               if(is_array($data) && count($data)){
                print_r($data);
               }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

this is the insert method

```
public function insert($data)
{
    $keys = array_keys($data);
    $columns = implode(',', $keys);
    $values = implode(',:', $keys);

    $query = "insert into $this->table ($columns) values (:$values)";

    return $this -> query($query,$data);
    //insert to the table
}
```

Comment: Do you want to read data or to write data? You can't do both.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243216/pdo-general-error-when-using-fetch-after-insert gives the answer (and some good advice)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDO general error when using fetch after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243216/pdo-general-error-when-using-fetch-after-insert)

Answer (score 1):

An INSERT query does not generate anything fetchable. As you have observed, PDO gacks (gacks === throws an obscure exception) when you try to use `.fetchAll()` from a statement containing INSERT.

**Edit** After you do `$stmt->execute($data)` on a data manipulation language (DML) statements (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE), don't call `$stmt->fetchAll()`. You'll need a different logic path for DML statements than for SELECT statements.

Comment: how can i handle it can you suggest a solution b/c this also happened when i try to implement update and delete not just insert